# do all schemes that are in BCNF also in 1NF?

Tags: database, database-design, bcnf

we are in 1NF if we don't have a non-atomic domains in our relation.

we are in BCNF if we don't have a functional dependency on the left hand side that is not a superkey.

as far as i know BCNF definition isn't concerned whether a relation has a non-atomic domains or not.

so i assume that not all BCNF schemes are in 1NF, and not all 1NF schemes are in BCNF.

i ask that question because i saw the following picture.

[image]

from the picture it looks like BCNF is subset of 3NF which is subset of 2NF which is subset of 1NF.

therefore it's the most restrictive.

so from that picture i kinda assume that BCNF schemes cannot have a non-atomic values.

but from where i read it, the definition never mentioned something about atomicity in BCNF.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Normalization in database management system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40623169/normalization-in-database-management-system)

Comment: Please use standard spelling & punctuation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1NF is not considered a normal form as the others, since nowadays it is considered implicit to the relational data model. In other worlds, if a table is not in 1NF, it is not a relation, while all the “other” normal forms are defined only for relations. So, obviously, any normal form from the second one, implicitly implies the so-called First Normal Form.